# wcf service with netmsmq and webhttpbinding endpoints

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF Service with multiple endpoints one is netmsmqbinding and other is webhttpbinding,when i tried to browse the service i am receiving following error "**Contract requires TwoWay (either request-reply or duplex), but Binding 'NetMsmqBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it."** i had added [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void myMethod(YourClass objectHere) to my netmsmq method and second method [OperationContract()] void mymethod() still getting the same error.

Below are my end points

please let me know if i am missing something.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="UpdateShipmentStatus" name="mydomian.UpdateShipmentStatus">

        <endpoint name="webHttpBinding" address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UpdateShipmentStatus" contract="mydomian.IUpdateShipmentStatus"></endpoint>

        <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/UpdateShipmentStatus.svc" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetMsmqBinding_IUpdateShipmentStatus" contract="mydomian.IUpdateShipmentStatus"/>

    <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://mydomian.com/xyz/UpdateShipmentStatus.svc" />
            <add baseAddress="net.msmq://localhost/private/UpdateShipmentStatus.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service> 

    bindings

    <binding name="NetMsmqBinding_IUpdateShipmentStatus"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" deadLetterQueue="System" durable="true" exactlyOnce="false" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" maxRetryCycles="2" receiveErrorHandling="Fault" receiveRetryCount="5" retryCycleDelay="00:30:00" timeToLive="1.00:00:00" useSourceJournal="false" useMsmqTracing="false" queueTransferProtocol="Native" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" useActiveDirectory="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" msmqEncryptionAlgorithm="RC4Stream" msmqProtectionLevel="Sign" msmqSecureHashAlgorithm="Sha1" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="UpdateShipmentStatus" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:00:00" sendTimeout="10:00:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="9223372036854775807" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807" transferMode="Streamed">
    <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
```

binding for MSMQ:

```
 <binding name="NetMsmqBinding_IUpdateShipmentStatus" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" >

  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" /> <security mode="None"> 

     <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" msmqEncryptionAlgorithm="RC4Stream" msmqProtectionLevel="Sign" msmqSecureHashAlgorithm="Sha1" />

 <message clientCredentialType="Windows" /> </security> </binding>
```

Comment: Please include the binding configuration "NetMsmqBinding_IUpdateShipmentStatus" in your post.

Comment: binding for MSMQ <binding name="NetMsmqBinding_IUpdateShipmentStatus"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" msmqEncryptionAlgorithm="RC4Stream" msmqProtectionLevel="Sign" msmqSecureHashAlgorithm="Sha1" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>